# android, servlet

Tags: android, struts2

I am writing an android application, which is sending some xml based data to struts2

In struts i retrieve the data and store it in a database.

But how can i send the same data to android in struts. give some code details with

explanation.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you done any research on this? A RESTful API might help with this

Answer (score 0):

Well, considering that the XML you're trying to send to the phone isn't an immediate answer to one of its requests, there are basically two routes you can go:

http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html

or

http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596007218

Unfortunately, both of them are too complex to be covered with a bit of example code.